# Populate picture box from eID vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi i got form that reads eID card, smart cards
text data reads correctly
picturebox name is picLK
but last statement is a picture

in VB6 and VBA I used

```
me.pctLK.Picture = ReaderEngine.portrait
```

ReaderEngine is procedure that reads data from card

when I use command in vb.net I get an error

```
me.pctLK = ReaderEngine.portrait
```

reader is reading card, but I got this message

> An unhandled exception of type '`System.InvalidCastException`' occurred in Project1.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type '`stdole.StdPictureClass`' to class type '`System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

I am new to VB .net

Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET has a helper function in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.Support` module, named `IPictureDispToImage`, which accepts an `StdPictureClass` object (which implements `IPictureDisp`) and returns a .NET `System.Drawing.Image` object which you can assign to the `PictureBox.Image` property. Be sure you appropriately dispose of the `Image` when you're finished with it:

```
Dim comImage As StdOle.StdPictureClass = ReaderEngine.portrait
If Me.picLK.Image Is Not Nothing Then
    Me.picLK.Image.Dispose()
    Me.picLK.Image = Nothing
End If

Dim newImage As System.Drawing.Image = Support.IPictureDispToImage( comImage )
Me.picLK.Image = newImage
```

Comment: Everything is working well until line dim newImage,there is no support option after equal sign, last two lines are not working, I use visual studio 2015